# How to get active class only in first div of carousel PHP

Tags: php, product, thumbnails

Friends thumb in the picture when the picture was selected, I could not do the Active incident.

```
<div id="carousel-product" class="carousel slide carousel-thumbnails mb-3" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <?php
        $alt_img = '';
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM urun_img WHERE urun_id = '{$urun['id']}'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($query->rowCount())
        {
            foreach($query as $row)
            {
                echo '<div class="carousel-item active"><img class="img-responsive" src="upload/'.$row['img'].'"></div>';
                $alt_img.= '<li data-target="#carousel-product" data-slide-to="1" class="verso-transition active"><img src="upload/'.$row['img'].'" alt="'.$urun['baslik'].'"></li>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators -mb--2">
        <?php echo $alt_img; ?>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/editing-help](/editing-help) for help on how to do so.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: ___One of a number of ways___ 
Make a flag variable. set it to true, if its true add the Active to the class list and set flag to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your if statement, you could simply do this:

```
$row_count = 1;
foreach($query as $row)
{
    echo '<div class="carousel-item'; if($row_count == 1) { echo ' active'; } echo '"><img class="img-responsive" src="upload/'.$row['img'].'"></div>';
    $alt_img.= '<li data-target="#carousel-product" data-slide-to="1" class="verso-transition active"><img src="upload/'.$row['img'].'" alt="'.$urun['baslik'].'"></li>';
    $row_count++;
}
```

To explain this:

- You create a $row_count variable with 1 at the value (this is the first row you're going to treat in your loop)
- You create a condition to say "if this is the first row only, then we add the class"
- You increment $row_count at the end of the loop, so for each new row, it will change its value to 2, then 3, then 4, etc... which then won't match the if($row_count == 1) condition.

Comment: thank you. it worked but thumbnails not working properly why?
demo: https://semihsahin.net/global/urun/ajans-scripti-28/

Comment: This is how I solved the problem, thank you again;

$row_count = 0;
                             foreach($query as $row){
     echo '<div class="carousel-item'; if($row_count == 1) { echo 'active'; } echo '"><img class="img-responsive" src="upload/'.$row[ 'img'].'"></div>';
     $alt_img.= '<li data-target="#carousel-product" data-slide-to="'.$row_count.'" class="verso-transition"><img src="upload/'.$row ['img'].'" alt="'.$product['title'].'"></li>';
     $row_count++;
}